# C#のメニューでShift+Enterを取得したい

Tags: c#

お世話になっております。
C#のContextMenuStripでShift+Enterを検出したいのですが、うまくいきません。
具体的にはクリックされた時のイベントでWindowsAPIのGetKeyStateでShiftキーの状態を取得しているんですが、そもそもShift+Enterではクリックしたときのイベントが起きないようです。
ちなみに、Shiftキーを押しながら、普通にマウスで左クリックしたときはうまくいくようです。
何か方法はあるでしょうか。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Shift' の状態だけを取るなら `Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)` で取れます。

例

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift))
            {
                this.label1.Text = "Shift ON";
            } 
            else
            {
                this.label1.Text = "Shift OFF";
            }
        }
```

> そもそもShift+Enterではクリックしたときのイベントが起きないようです。

あ、こっちのほうが問題だったんですね。
contextMenuStrip1 PrevKeyDown イベント の中で キーを判定して SHIFT + RETURN の場合に
選択されている メニューを呼び出すようにコーディングしてみました。

```
this.contextMenuStrip1.PreviewKeyDown += 
new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(this.contextMenuStrip1_PreviewKeyDown);
```

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)
        && e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Return))
    {
        var cMenu = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
        if (cMenu != null)
        {
            var selectItem = cMenu.Items.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>()
                    .Where(r => r.Selected == true).FirstOrDefault();

            selectItem?.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

それっぽく動作すると思います。

Comment: 説明がわかりにくくて、すみませんでした。教えていただいたコードでやりたいことが実現できました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

この記事がVBの質問でEnterキーのことですが、同様のことを扱っています。
[KeyDown event doesn't fire on ContextMenuStrip with enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20751326/9014308)
質問

> .NET : I have a Context menu strip that I want to handle using keyboard keys.
>   I have the following event handler:
>
> ```
> Private Sub ContextMenuEnterKey(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As KeyEventArgs) Handles ContextMenu.KeyDown
>     If E.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
>         'Do some staff
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```
>
> The events fires correctly with other keys except EnterKey.
>   Does anyone know what's wrong with that ?

回答

> To which control's KeyDown event are you binding your handler? In the Forms designer the ? KeyDown event isn't even shown for ContextMenuStrip (at least here in VS2012, and I'm working in C#...) I can bind to in in code, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.
>
> But there is a PreviewKeyDown event in ContextMenuStrip which gets called for every keystroke within the context menu, also for the Enter key. Maybe this can help you?
>
> ただし、ContextMenuStripにはPreviewContextDownイベントがあり、コンテキストメニュー内のすべてのキーストロークに対して、またEnterキーに対しても呼び出されます。
>   たぶんこれはあなたを助けることができますか？

---

こんな感じで登録しておけば：

```
this.contextMenuStrip1.PreviewKeyDown += ContextMenuStrip1_PreviewKeyDown;
```

こちらのイベントハンドラで入力されたキーの処理がCtrl/Alt/Shift併押下判断も含めてできます。
ただしカーソルを動かした等の全部のキーが入ってきます。

```
private void ContextMenuStrip1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IsInputKey={0}, KeyCode={1}, KeyData={2}, KeyValue={3}, Modifiers={4}\n", e.IsInputKey.ToString(), e.KeyCode.ToString("X"),e.KeyData.ToString("X"),e.KeyValue.ToString("X"),e.Modifiers.ToString("X"));
}
```

参考：
[Control.PreviewKeyDown イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.8)
[PreviewKeyDownEventArgs クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs?view=netframework-4.8)

> ```
> プロパティ
> Alt         Alt キーが押されたかどうかを示す値を取得します。
> Control     Ctrl キーが押されたかどうかを示す値を取得します。
> IsInputKey  キーが通常の入力キーであるかどうかを示す値を取得または設定します。
> KeyCode     KeyDown イベントまたは KeyUp イベントのキーボード コードを取得します。
> KeyData     KeyDown や KeyUp イベントに対する SHIFT、CONTROL、ALT キーなどのキー修正子と組み合わせたキー コードを取得します。
> KeyValue    KeyDown イベントまたは KeyUp イベントのキーボード値を取得します。
> Modifiers   KeyDown イベントまたは KeyUp イベントの修飾フラグを取得します。
> Shift       Shift キーが押されたかどうかを示す値を取得します。
> ```

[コントロールで矢印、Tab、Enter、Escキーが押されたことを知る](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/btndetectarraykey.html)

> PreviewKeyDownイベントはKeyDownイベントの前に発生します。KeyDownやKeyUpイベントが発生しないようなキーが押された場合も発生し、押されたキーを知ることができます。
>   さらに、KeyDownやKeyUpイベントが発生しないようなキーが押された場合でも、PreviewKeyDownイベントハンドラでPreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKeyプロパティをTrueにすることにより、KeyDownやKeyUpイベントが発生するようになります。ただしこの場合は、そのキー本来の機能（例えば、矢印キーであれば、フォーカスの移動）は失われます。

Comment: 「PreviewKeyDown」でうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。